# How to parse multi-line Java EE logs with a different time stamp format splunkstorm

Tags: splunk

I have logs which look like this:

> Jun 19, 2012 7:15:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
>
> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

The timestamp does not follow ISO 8601. Is there any way I can achieve segregation based on the above format? Right now it is randomly clubbing multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Create new sourcetype in splunk as

```
[javaee_logs]
BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE=^\w\w\w\s\d{2},\s\d{4}\s\d+:\d{2}:\d{2}
NO_BINARY_CHECK=1
SHOULD_LINEMERGE=true
TIME_FORMAT=%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p
TIME_PREFIX=^
```